# Database connection troubleshooting

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connector

I recently picked up C# programming and am hoping to read in tables from mySQL tables and display them in DataGridView controls. The tables are generated using PHP scripts and I am able to login to my database. In PHP I am using the following connection string:

@mysql_connect('localhost:3307','root','password_string');

In C#, I am using the following connection string:

string MyConString = @"Server=localhost;Database=database_name;User ID=root;Password=password_string";

When I run the program, I get the following message in the console:

"Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' "

I've tried making countless changes to the connection string by using single quotes, using localhost:3307, etc. I've granted privileges for user root, so I don't think that is the issue. How do I get past this? Is there some problem with the connector I have. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: check your password. you might have password error.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you are connecting to the non standard port 3307. You can specify this in the .NET connection string with `port=3307`:

```
string MyConString = @"Server=localhost;Database=database_name;User ID=root;Password=password_string;port=3307";
```

Comment: You're very welcome. Have you considered accepting the answer?

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to PRIVILEGES may be user name do'nt have the required PRIVILEGES

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost'
```

**Other reason may be**

This is not possible, as the client always uses a socket to connect to "localhost" (which is the default host). For a sucessful connection either the combination of localhost + socket or 127.0.0.1 + port must be specified.

kimiko:~ # mysql -h127.0.0.1 -P3307 -ptest

kimiko:~ # mysql -S/path/to/mysql.sock -ptest